# Module Fedration :- While a new module is loaded onto the container whole layout (or the app is re-rendered)

Tags: webpack-5, rerender

Here is my system.js code for loading a component

```
export const loadComponent = (scope, module) => async () => {
    // Initializes the share scope. This fills it with known provided modules from this build and all remotes
    await __webpack_init_sharing__('modern');
    const container = window[scope]; // or get the container somewhere else
    // Initialize the container, it may provide shared modules
    await container.init(__webpack_share_scopes__.default);
    const factory = await window[scope].get(module);
    const Module = factory();
    return Module;
};
```

I have a sidebar and a header which re-renders every-time I navigate to a different page from the side bar.
Here is my layout.js code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Header from '../header/header';
import Sidebar from '../sidebar/sidebar';
import './layout.scss';

const Layout = (props) => {
    console.log(props, "props")
    const [isIframe, setIsIframe] = useState(false);
    const [branchIdFromUrl, setBranchIdFromUrl] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const query = window?.location?.search;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(query);
        const iframe = urlParams.get('iif');
        const branch = urlParams.get('branchId');

        if (iframe) {
            setIsIframe(true);
        }
        if (branch) {
            setBranchIdFromUrl(branch);
        }
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            <Header isIframe={isIframe} branchIdFromUrl={branchIdFromUrl} />
            <div className={isIframe ? 'main-wrapper-without-padding' : 'main-wrapper'}>
                <div className="flex h-full">
                    <Sidebar />
                    <div className="flex-grow">
                        <div className="content-wrapper overflow-auto">
                            {/* <SearchBar/> */}
                            {/* <BreadCrumb/> */}
                            <div className="p-5">{props.children}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Layout;
```

If any more information is needed let me know.